# GetElementById is not a function?

Tags: javascript

When running this script i get an error message that document.GetElementById is not a function?? - You can see the site at: http://www.fritidsjobbere.dk:

```
//Show random div with Javascript
antal = 6;
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*antal);
if(randomnumber == "0") {
randomnumber = 1;
}
//alert(randomnumber);
document.getElementsById("partner-ad"+randomnumber).style.display = 'block';
```

Answer (score 14):

`getElementsById` -> `getElementById`

Answer (score 2):

It's singular (IDs are unique, it should only return one result), [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementByID) like this:

```
document.getElementById("partner-ad"+randomnumber).style.display = 'block';
```

---

Also, your *actual* code on the site differs from your question, it's `document.getElementsByID` on the actual page...make sure that `ID` is `Id` as well.

---

Another side-note, since your ads are `partner-ad1` through `partner-ad6`, your current code would never show the `6th` ad, you can simplify it and fix that issue like this:

```
var antal = 6;
var randomnumber=Math.ceil(Math.random()*antal); //instead of Math.floor
document.getElementById("partner-ad"+randomnumber+"").style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: Ahh ok, thx :) Anyway, that created another problem - Now i get the error message that document.getElementById("partner-ad"+randomnumber+"").style.display = 'block';
 is null ? - But if i alert randomnumber i get a number ?

Comment: Yes, but there is no guarantee there is an element in the DOM with this id.

Comment: @nickycdk - Your `<script>` occurs *before* the elements with those IDs in the page, move the `<script>` *after* them so they'll be in the DOM ready to find.

Answer (score 2):

Are you confusing `getElementById` and `getElementsByTagName`. Note the former is singular, and the latter is plural.

Of course, if you're using jQuery (as your tag intimates), you needn't be using either, as you can just use the #ID selector:

```
$("#partner-ad"+randomnumber").show();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementsById("partner-ad"+randomnumber).style.display = 'block';
```

Should be

```
document.getElementById("partner-ad"+randomnumber).style.display = 'block';
```

Why not do this using jQuery by the way?